# StereoEffect + Multiple Scenes = No

Tags: three.js

I have two scenes: scene1 and scene2.  I have two cameras: camera1 and camera2

- scene1 is the background and uses camera1
- scene2 simulates a head-up display and uses camera2 (so changes to camera1 FOV do not affect element positions)

I can render (composite) scene2 on top of scene1 just fine when StereoEffect is not used.

However I cannot render scene 2 on top of scene1 when using the StereoEffect.
The StereoEffect will only render a single scene and a single camera. It appears it cannot render (composite) multiple scenes on top of each other. I have also tried creating multiple renderers, such as renderer2, which I applied to the StereoEffect - such as `stereo = new THREE.StereoEffect(renderer2)` but this also did not work.

Thoughts ?

Comment: Your title isn't a proper question. You've not specified what type of cameras you are using. And most importantly, you've not shared any code. Can you provide a jsfiddle so people can look at your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you want to render once on all the canvas for your main scene, and once at the bottom-center for your head-up display. `THREE.StereoEffect` indeed asks for only one scene, and to get a *stereo* effect. It was not written for what you describe.

It uses `scissors` to render once on the left, then on the right part of the canvas. Scissors allow you to change the area of the canvas you are drawing into. As you can see in the source of `THREE.StereoEffect` :

```
renderer.setScissor( 0, 0, _width, _height );
renderer.setViewport( 0, 0, _width, _height );
renderer.render( scene, _cameraL );

renderer.setScissor( _width, 0, _width, _height );
renderer.setViewport( _width, 0, _width, _height );
renderer.render( scene, _cameraR );
```

The four parameters of the `setScissor` and `setViewport` methods are *start abscissa (**from left**), start ordinate (**from bottom**), width, height (all parameters are pixel numbers)*.

Knowing this you can use scissors for what you need, without `THREE.StereoEffect`. So first write in the first part of your code :`renderer.enableScissorTest(true)`. Then in your loop, copy the code above with what you need : scissors and viewport covering all the screen for your first rendering, then covering only the head-up part for the second.

Comment: @ Atrahasis This solution worked perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: By the way, when using setScissor don't forget to change your camera aspect. Otherwise there will be visual anomalies.

Comment: @villmer could you please write something more about camera aspect?

Comment: I set `camera.aspect = (width / 2) / height` and called `camera.updateProjectionMatrix()`.